# How to use Long_callback with multipage app in Dash Plotly?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I'm trying to build a multi page Dash App with Long Callback . When I run the app with Single page Application , it is working fine .Working code is given Below

SinglePage.py

```
import json
import dash
from dash import html, dcc
from dash.long_callback import DiskcacheLongCallbackManager
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

## Diskcache
import diskcache

from query_4_entity_explr import get_ORG_info, get_daterange_entity_dataframe

cache = diskcache.Cache("./cache")
long_callback_manager = DiskcacheLongCallbackManager(cache)

app = dash.Dash("topx_org",
                long_callback_manager=long_callback_manager,
                external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP],
                meta_tags=[{'name': 'viewport', 'content': 'initial-scale=1'}])

today = datetime.datetime.today().date()
date_30_day_back = (datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)).date()

app.layout = dbc.Container([
    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col(html.H3("Explore Organizations mentioned in media", className='text-center text-primary py-5'), width=12)
    ]),
    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col(dbc.Label(['Select daterange']), width={'size': 2, 'offset': 0}),
        dbc.Col(dcc.DatePickerRange(id='input_date_picker_range', display_format='YYYY-MM-DD', start_date=date_30_day_back, end_date=today), width={'size':10, 'offset':0}),
    ], justify='around', className='mb-1'),
    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col(dbc.Label(['Choose Companies with mention count']), width=2),
        dbc.Col(dcc.Dropdown(id = "input_item_dropdown", options =  [], value=[], multi=True), width=10),

    ], justify='around', className='mb-1'),
    # dbc.Row(dbc.Button(id="cancel_button_id", children="Cancel Running Job!")),
    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col(html.Div(id="output_text", children=[]), width={'size':10, 'offset':2}),

    ], justify='around', className='py-3'),

    dbc.Row([
                html.Progress(id="progress_bar"),
            ]),

    dbc.Row([

        dbc.Col(dcc.Graph(id='output_graph', figure={}), width=12),

    ], justify='around', className='py-5'),

    dcc.Store(id='stored-dataframe')
])


@app.long_callback(
    [Output(component_id='output_text', component_property='children'),
     Output(component_id="input_item_dropdown", component_property="options"),
     Output(component_id='stored-dataframe', component_property='data'),
     ],
    [Input(component_id="input_date_picker_range", component_property="start_date"),
     Input(component_id="input_date_picker_range", component_property="end_date"),
     ],
    manager=long_callback_manager,
    running=[
        (Output("output_text", "disabled"), False, True),
        (
            Output("output_graph", "style"),
            {"visibility": "hidden"},
            {"visibility": "visible"},
        ),
        (
            Output("progress_bar", "style"),
            {"visibility": "visible"},
            {"visibility": "hidden"},
        ),
    ],
)


def update_figure(start_date, end_date):

    print(start_date)
    print(end_date)

    # Data Acquisition
    TOP_N = 20
    unique_org_list, top_companys, org_gp_pdf = get_ORG_info(get_daterange_entity_dataframe(start_date,end_date), TOP_N)

    # For the div
    # _text = str(f"Between {start_date} to {end_date} for all the organizations : { ', '.join (item_list_value) }")
    _text = str(f"Between {start_date} to {end_date} there are {len(unique_org_list)} organizations mentioned in media.")

    # Store the data in browser storage.
    datasets = {
        'so_1': org_gp_pdf.to_json(orient='split', date_format='iso'),
        'so_2': top_companys,
    }

    return [_text], [{'label': str(c[0]) + f"  ({c[1]})", 'value': str(c[0])} for c in unique_org_list[0:]], json.dumps(datasets)


@app.callback(
    [Output(component_id='output_graph', component_property='figure')],
    [Input(component_id="input_item_dropdown", component_property="value"),
     Input(component_id='stored-dataframe', component_property='data')
    ],
    progress=[Output("progress_bar", "value"), Output("progress_bar", "max")],
)

def update_graph_2(item_list_value, jsonified_cleaned_data):
    # Load the stored DF and List from Browser storage
    datasets = json.loads(jsonified_cleaned_data)
    df_2 = pd.read_json(datasets['so_1'], orient='split')
    top_companys = datasets['so_2']

    if len(item_list_value) == 0:
        fig = px.bar( df_2[df_2.ORG.isin(top_companys)].sort_values(['NEWS_DATE'], ascending=True), title=f"Showing top {len(top_companys)} organizations", x="NEWS_DATE", y="COUNT", color="ORG", barmode="group")  # .query("ORG=='Mentice' | ORG=='Isofol Medical AB'")
    else:
        queryString = " | ".join([f"ORG=='{item}'" for item in item_list_value])
        fig = px.bar(df_2.query(queryString).sort_values(['NEWS_DATE'], ascending=True) ,title=f"Showing some selected organizations", x="NEWS_DATE", y="COUNT", color="ORG", barmode="group")  # .query("ORG=='Mentice' | ORG=='Isofol Medical AB'")
        # align title
    fig.update_layout(title_x=0.5, xaxis=dict(title_text='NEWS PUBLISH DATE'), yaxis=dict(title_text='DAILY ORG MENTION COUNT '))
    return [fig]


if _name_ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(port=8050, debug=False)
```

But When i am trying run the same application in multipage structure it is showing me @long_callback is not callable.
In Multipage structure my main App file is given below
app.py

```
from pages import topx_org, topx_per

import dash
from dash import html, dcc
from dash.long_callback import DiskcacheLongCallbackManager
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc


## Diskcache
import diskcache


cache = diskcache.Cache("./cache")
long_callback_manager = DiskcacheLongCallbackManager(cache)

app = dash.Dash(__name__,
           suppress_callback_exceptions=True,
           long_callback_manager=long_callback_manager,
           external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP],
           meta_tags=[{'name': 'viewport', 'content': 'initial-scale=1'}])

server = app.server

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Location(id='url', refresh=False),
    html.Div(id='page-content')
])


@app.callback(Output('page-content', 'children'),
              Input('url', 'pathname'))
def display_page(pathname):
    if pathname == '/topx_org':
        return topx_org.layout
    elif pathname == '/topx_per':
        return topx_per.layout
    else:
        return '404'


if _name_ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

and the topx_org.py is given below

```
from dash import callback, long_callback
import json
from dash import html, dcc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
from query_4_entity_explr import get_ORG_info, get_daterange_entity_dataframe

today = datetime.datetime.today().date()
date_30_day_back = (datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)).date()

layout = dbc.Container([
    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col(html.H3("Explore Organizations mentioned in media", className='text-center text-primary py-5'), width=12)
    ]),
    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col(dbc.Label(['Select daterange' ]), width={'size':2, 'offset':0}),
        dbc.Col(dcc.DatePickerRange(id='input_date_picker_range', display_format='YYYY-MM-DD',start_date=date_30_day_back, end_date=today), width={'size':10, 'offset':0}),

    ], justify='around', className='mb-1'),
    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col(dbc.Label(['Choose Companies with mention count']), width=2),
        dbc.Col(dcc.Dropdown(id = "input_item_dropdown", options =  [], value=[], multi=True), width=10),

    ], justify='around', className='mb-1'),
    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col(html.Div(id="output_text", children=[]), width={'size':10, 'offset':2}),

    ], justify='around', className='py-3'),

    dbc.Row([

        dbc.Col(dcc.Graph(id='output_graph', figure={}), width=12),

    ], justify='around', className='py-5'),

    dcc.Store(id='stored-dataframe')
])


# Output(component_id='output_graph', component_property='figure'),
@callback(
    [Output(component_id='output_text', component_property='children'),
     Output(component_id="input_item_dropdown", component_property="options"),
     Output(component_id='stored-dataframe', component_property='data'),
     ],
    [Input(component_id="input_date_picker_range", component_property="start_date"),
     Input(component_id="input_date_picker_range", component_property="end_date"),
     ],
    progress=[Output("progress_bar", "value"), Output("progress_bar", "max")],
)

def update_figure(start_date, end_date):
    print(start_date)
    print(end_date)
    # print(item_list_value)

    # Data Acquisition
    TOP_N = 20
    unique_org_list, top_companys, org_gp_pdf = get_ORG_info(get_daterange_entity_dataframe(start_date,end_date), TOP_N)

    # For the div
    # _text = str(f"Between {start_date} to {end_date} for all the organizations : { ', '.join (item_list_value) }")
    _text = str(f"Between {start_date} to {end_date} there are {len(unique_org_list)} organizations mentioned in media.")

    # Store the data in browser storage.
    datasets = {
        'so_1': org_gp_pdf.to_json(orient='split', date_format='iso'),
        'so_2': top_companys,
    }

    return [_text], [{'label': str(c[0]) + f"  ({c[1]})", 'value': str(c[0])} for c in unique_org_list[0:]], json.dumps(datasets)


@long_callback(
    [Output(component_id='output_graph', component_property='figure')],
    [Input(component_id="input_item_dropdown", component_property="value"),
     Input(component_id='stored-dataframe', component_property='data')
    ],
    running=[
        (Output("output_text", "disabled"), False, True),
        (
            Output("output_graph", "style"),
            {"visibility": "hidden"},
            {"visibility": "visible"},
        ),
        (
            Output("progress_bar", "style"),
            {"visibility": "visible"},
            {"visibility": "hidden"},
        ),
    ],
)
def update_graph_2(item_list_value, jsonified_cleaned_data):
    # Load the stored DF and List from Browser storage
    datasets = json.loads(jsonified_cleaned_data)
    df_2 = pd.read_json(datasets['so_1'], orient='split')
    top_companys = datasets['so_2']

    if len(item_list_value) == 0:
        fig = px.bar( df_2[df_2.ORG.isin(top_companys)].sort_values(['NEWS_DATE'], ascending=True), title=f"Showing top {len(top_companys)} organizations", x="NEWS_DATE", y="COUNT", color="ORG", barmode="group")  # .query("ORG=='Mentice' | ORG=='Isofol Medical AB'")
    else:
        queryString = " | ".join([f"ORG=='{item}'" for item in item_list_value])
        fig = px.bar(df_2.query(queryString).sort_values(['NEWS_DATE'], ascending=True) ,title=f"Showing some selected organizations", x="NEWS_DATE", y="COUNT", color="ORG", barmode="group")  # .query("ORG=='Mentice' | ORG=='Isofol Medical AB'")
        # align title
    fig.update_layout(title_x=0.5, xaxis=dict(title_text='NEWS PUBLISH DATE'), yaxis=dict(title_text='DAILY ORG MENTION COUNT '))
    return [fig]
```

I am having the following error

```
 @long_callback(
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Comment: Hello, did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: no. i think we can't use this right now. may be in future. i re-structured my application for now

Answer (score 2):

This is now possible in the latest dash version by using the function `app = dash.get_app()` and then calling `@app.long_callback`.

Answer (score 1):

(Updated) According to [this post](https://community.plotly.com/t/how-to-make-long-callback-work-with-multipagedashapp/59475), this is not possible yet because long_callback requires the app object (@app.long_callback). If you try to import the app object in your page file, you will create a circular import which will cause an error.

The only possibility mentionned in the post is to put all the long callbacks in the app.py file. The 'normal' callbacks and the layout can stay in the pages files.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32018226)

Answer (score 0):

In the current version of Dash, you can enable background callbacks for a multipage app like so:

myapp.py

```
from celery import Celery
import dash
import os

_app = None
_background_callback_manager = None
_celery_app = None

def _get_app():
    global _app
    if _app is None:
        _app = dash.Dash(
            __name__,
            background_callback_manager=_get_background_callback_manager(),
        )
    return _app


def _get_background_callback_manager():
    global _background_callback_manager
    if _background_callback_manager is None:
        _background_callback_manager = dash.CeleryManager(_get_celery_app())
    return _background_callback_manager


def _get_celery_app():
    global _celery_app
    if _celery_app is None:
        _celery_app = Celery(
            __name__,
            broker=os.getenv("REDIS_URL"),
            backend=os.getenv("REDIS_URL"),
        )
        default_config = "celeryconfig"
        _celery_app.config_from_object(default_config)
    return _celery_app

app = _get_app()
celery_app = _get_celery_app()
```

The celery config, looks like this an needs to import any module where there's an app.callback() where background=True:

celeryconfig.py

```
## See https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html

# List of modules to import when the Celery worker starts
# i.e. anywhere an @app.callback has background=True
imports = ("module1", "module2")
```

And in the modules, the callbacks look like this:

module1.py

```
from myapp import app
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

@app.callback(
    Output("my-output", "children"),
    Input("my-input", "value"),
    background=True,
)
def my_callback(_):
    return long_running_query()
```

Also, the Celery worker needs to be started with something like:

```
celery --app=myapp.celery_app worker --loglevel=INFO
```